How to solve blue screen issue coming even after using a USB media?
I have an HP-i3-7th bought in 2018. I had dual booted it 4 years ago with Win default and Ubuntu secondary. A year ago it started malfunctioning because the boot would not work properly. If Ubuntu is set default OS then GRUB terminal appears while when Win is set as default Blue Screen appears with error code 0xc0000034.
I searched some and found that a USB media with windows creation can work. So I made a UEFI-NTFS of windows. The boot options priorities are set to USB first. After using this USB the boot starts, HP logo is seen which would not appear otherwise. However, after that only blue screen appears with nothing written on it. Though I can hover the pointer on this screen there is nothing to hover to.
Has anybody else faced this problem and have any solution for this? Thanks
PS: Secure boot is disabled.

Windows 7?? Just copy the Windows apps to Ubuntu and run them in wine.

@DrMoishePippik can’t even enter using any booting method


Enable Secure Boot. 2. Make a Ubuntu Live USB to run Ubuntu from USB. 3. If that works, then install it as the only OS, after saving data. 3. If it does not boot Ubuntu from USB, then likely there is a serious hardware issue.

